# C++ find highest element in array that isant a particular value

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using some data that uses some an extremely high value as an error code. I am currently using std max element, is there a way to do this ignoring a particular value?. eg max element that isant a particular number.

Comment: why isn't scanning from start to finish and finding the max ok?

Comment: Because there is a value in the dataset that is an error code for something else that I would like to ignore for this calculation.

Comment: e.g find max but ignore  all values of 55505. Obviously I can iterate just wondering if there is an simple method considering its only one value.

Comment: Use `std::max_element` with a (lambda) function `comp` to tell if a value is bigger than another. Implement it, such that e.g. 55505 is the smallest element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, let's use a custom comparator as part of the call to `std::max_element`. We'll just make sure that if we see the error code, then we'll make that smaller than all other elements.

```
auto maxElement = std::max_element(std::begin(container), std::end(container), [](T const & lhs, T const & rhs) -> bool {
    if (rhs == error_code)
         return false;
    if (lhs == error_code)
         return true;
    return lhs < rhs;
}
```

Comment: I would move `rhs` test first to satisfy `(t < t) == false`.

Comment: @Jarod42: I was thinking about if we'd need a case for `lhs == rhs == error_code` but that should cover it as well. Good idea.